# npm run script < was unexpected

Tags: javascript, npm, escaping, package.json, npm-scripts

I recently read an [article](https://coderwall.com/p/5cv5lg/generate-your-changelogs-with-git-log) about generating a changelog and I wanted to integrate it in a package.json script.

I changed the script from the article a bit with the proper project name and to export the output to CHANGELOG.md

```
 "scripts": {
    "generateChangelog": "git log --pretty=format:'<li> <a href=\"http://git.egt-interactive.com/frontend-games/temporary-test-project/commit/%H\">view commit &bull;</a> %s</li> ' --reverse > CHANGELOG.md"
 },
```

But when I run it I have the following error:

> ```
> < was unexpected at this time.
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! temporary-test-project@1.0.0 generateChangelog: `git log --pretty=format:'<li> <a href="http://git.egt-interactive.com/frontend-games/temporary-test-project/commit/%H">view commit &bull;</a> %s</li> ' --reverse > CHANGELOG.md`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> ```

I think it's something with the escaping, but I can't find it.

Would be glad for some help. Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT**

I am working on windows and  by default, I am using Powershell, but I tried to run `npm run generateChangelog` script with cmd too ( both failed )

However, if I run the same `git log...` command directly in the shell it works:

```
git log --pretty=format:'<li> <a href=\"http://git.egt-interactive.com/frontend-games/temporary-test-project/commit/%H\">view commit &bull;</a> %s</li> ' --reverse > CHANGELOG.md`
```

Comment: Did you try to use it like this? `git log --pretty=format:'<li> <a href="http://git.egt-interactive.com/frontend-games/temporary-test-project/commit/%H">view commit &bull;</a> %s</li> ' --reverse > CHANGELOG.md`

Comment: @GillesHeinesch first time copying it , but I don't think its a valid JSON for sure like that or at least my editor highlight's it in red this way

Comment: Did you try to use my code from my comment?

Comment: @GillesHeinesch yes , but it throws different exception  
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it's something with the escaping, but I can't find it.

Yes, you're correct it's an escaping issue.

Change your script named `generateChangelog` in the `scripts` section of your *package.json* to the following:

```json
"scripts": {
  "generateChangelog": "git log --pretty=format:\"<li> <a href=\\\"http://git.egt-interactive.com/frontend-games/temporary-test-project/commit/%H\\\">view commit &bull;</a> %s</li> \" --reverse > CHANGELOG.md"
},
```

Note the changes:

- The single quotes (`'`) have been replaced with JSON escaped double quotes (`\"`)
- The JSON escaped double quotes (`\"`) have been replaced with (`\\\"`)

```json
git log --pretty=format:\"<li> <a href=\\\"http://git.egt-interactive.com/frontend-games/temporary-test-project/commit/%H\\\">view commit &bull;</a> %s</li>\" --reverse > CHANGELOG.md
                        ^^             ^^^^                                                                              ^^^^                               ^^
```

Running `$ npm run generateChangelog` should now run successfully via:

- Windows Powershell
- Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe)
- Windows Git Bash
- **Nix* command-line tools